# Работа перегрузки операторов

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Объясните, как работает функция перегрузки операторов? Какие новые объекты создаются в этот момент? Как работает указатель `this`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оператор - это точно такая же функция, как и любая другая, только с определенным заранее приоритетом и количеством аргументов. Так что

```
class X {
    X& operator + (int y);
```

по сути ничем не отличается от

```
class X {
    X& add(int y);
```

Только и того, что можно написать

```
x.add(5);
```

а можно

```
x + 5;
```

или

```
x.operator+(5);
```

Объекты создаются ровно те, которые вы укажете создать. А `this`, как и всегда, имеет смысл только в операторе-члене и указывает на объект класса, для которого вызван оператор.

Comment: o3 = o1 + o2;  тут this будет указывать на о1?

Comment: Если оператор + является членом класса, то эта запись будет трактоваться как `o3=o1.operator+(o2)` и, как вы и написали, `this` будет указывать на `o1`.